# Another quick T/F Complex Variables question

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Why is the above statement true? What if $fg$ is a constant function?? (for example, if $f(z)=e^z$ and $g(z)=\frac 1{e^z}$)

(I *think* that the above is true if $fg$ is definitely non-constant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, suppose that there exists $z_0\in G$ such that $\forall R>0$ , with $D'(z_0,R)\subset G$ there exists $z_R\in D'(z_0,R)$ such that:
$$f(z_R)g(z_R)=-f(z_R)-g(z_R)-1$$
Now take a (decreasing) sequence of radii $R_n\rightarrow 0$ such that $D'(z_0,R_n)\subset G$. For each $n\in\mathbb N$ there exists $z_n\in D'(z_0,R_n)$ such that: $$0<|z_0-z_n|<R_n\text { and}$$
$$f(z_n)g(z_n)=-f(z_n)-g(z_n)-1$$
Therefore we obtain that $z_n\rightarrow z_0$ from the first relation, while the second implies that $$f(z)g(z)=-f(z)-g(z)-1$$ for all $z\in G$ (by the Identity Principle).

So, $$(g(z)+1)(f(z)+1)=0\Rightarrow$$
$$\begin{cases}f(z)=-1 ,\text{ for infinite }z\in G\\\text{or}\\g(z)=-1,\text{ for infinite }z\in G\end{cases}\Rightarrow $$
$f$ is constant or $g$ is constant ( again using the identity principle), which contradicts our hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Suppose there exists $\,b\in G\,$ s.t. for any punctured disk around it of positive radius there exists some point $\,z_0\,$ in it s.t.:

$$f(z_0)g(z_0)=-f(z_0)-g(z_0)-1\iff (f(z_0)+1)(g(z_0)+1)=0\;\;\ldots$$